# Get sibling value when parsing JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm parsing a JSON file in PHP and ran into some issues with a data structure that I can't figure out how to make sense of. This is what one data node looks like:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "title": "Some title",
        "subtitle": "Some subtitle",
        "description": "Some description",
        "labels": [{
            "type": "itemId",
            "raw": "someId12345"
        }, {
            "type": "itemtype",
            "raw": "general"
        }]
    }]
}
```

This is the very basic code I'm using:

```
$url = 'data.json';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($content, true);

foreach($json['data'] as $item) {
    return $item['title'];
    return $item['description'];
}
```

Getting the title and description works, but I'm struggling with those labels. I would like to get the "raw" value for the type itemId (ie. someId12345) but I can't figure out how. The labels aren't in a fixed order, otherwise I could just use something like this to get the ID:

```
return $item['labels'][0]['raw'];
```

I tried creating a separate foreach but that only gives me an unidentified index on all values.

```
foreach($json['data'] as $ID) {
    if($ID['labels']['itemId'] == $_GET['labels']['itemId']) {
        return $ID['raw'];
        break;
        }
}
```

How can I get the sibling value so I'd end up with this data:

```
Some title
Some description
someId12345
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't different from what you're already doing:

```
foreach ($json['data'] as $item) {
  foreach ($item['labels'] as $label) {
    var_dump($label['raw']);
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/IRKw/1)

To filter by `type` you can use an `if` construct:

```
if ($label['type'] === 'itemId') {
  var_dump($label['raw']);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works for getting all raw values but I'd like to single out the raw value associated with the itemId type. How would I go about doing that?